# Count total number of alias in a JKS file and check if a particular alias is also present using keytool command in a bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, keystore, keytool

I am writing a bat file with keytool command that reads the JKS file and checks the alias name. I want count the total number of aliases because a JKS file can have multiple aliases and if the alias foo is present, I want to set isAliasFoo as true. I tried below code to count aliases, but the totalNumberOfAlias always prints 0. Instead I was expecting it to increment by 1 each time new alias is present.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set totalNumberOfAlias=0
set isAliasFooPresent="false"

start cmd /c "keytool -list -v -keystore %JKSPath%" -storepass %password% | for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /c:Alias') do (set totalNumberOfAlias= totalNumberOfAlias+1)"
Exit
```

Lets assume the alias foo is present among five other aliases. I would like following echo statement print 5 and true respectively.

```
echo totalNumberOfAlias is : %totalNumberOfAlias% 
echo isAliasFoo %isAliasFooPresent%
```

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are missing the `/A` option with the `SET` command for starters.

Comment: I suggest you to do this into the FOR command: `set /A alias[%%a]+=1, total+=1` where `%%a` is a replaceable parameter that have the alias (it is up to you to get it). After that, you may do `if defined alias[foo] ...` or `if defined alias[bar] ...` etc. and `total` variable should have to total number of alias (you missed `/A` switch in `SET` command, as @Squashman said)...

Comment: It still prints 0 in the echo statement.